# Euler problem 21, why are there extra numbers in my solution?

Tags: python, math

The following is my code to solve [Euler #21, Evaluate the sum of all the amicable numbers under 10000](https://projecteuler.net/problem=21).

```py
def divisor_sum(x):
    divisor_sum=0
    for i in range(1,x):
        if x%i==0:
            divisor_sum = divisor_sum + i
    return(divisor_sum)

for a in range (10000):
    if divisor_sum(divisor_sum(a)) == a:
        print(a)
```

The response is:

```
0
6
28
220
284
496
1184
1210
2620
2924
5020
5564
6232
6368
8128
```

I know it wants the sums, but in order to check my code I ran what numbers it was summing since the sum was wrong.

The odd thing is that when I [look online](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1967-21-098/S0025-5718-1967-0222006-7/S0025-5718-1967-0222006-7.pdf) all of the numbers that should be here are found except 0, 6, 28, 496, 8128.

What is going on?

Comment: 6 is not amicable, because the question says `a != b`. Same goes for 28

Comment: I would go `b = divisor_sum(a); if a != b and a == divisor_sum(b):`

Comment: Thank you solved it. For anyone curious the way I fixed it was by adding the following in the second to last line : '''if divisor_sum(a)!=a'''

Comment: It is actually explained in the article you linked: `(M; N), M < N,`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your program is finding **perfect numbers** as well as amicable numbers: 0, 6, 28, 496, and 8128 are the first five perfect numbers. Remember that amicable numbers come in pairs; the first five perfect numbers do not and by definition cannot have a matching pair that would make them an amicable number.

By definition, a perfect number's divisors will sum back to the perfect number, meaning `divisor_sum(divisor_sum(6))` == `divisor_sum(6)`

Edit: As commenters pointed out as I was writing this, you need something like:

```
if divisor_sum(a)!=a
```