# Python Project Euler # 21

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having a bit of trouble with [Project Euler # 21](https://projecteuler.net/problem=21), and even though (for me) it seems that it should work, I can't arrive at the correct answer. Tweaks to the iterating range did not seem to help.

I understood the process behind finding the proper divisors and I wrote code that used that process to find the Amicable numbers. The code worked before when I used the original number on the site example, 220.

```python
def amicable_number(x):
    amic_range = range(1, x)
    amicable_numbers = []

    for num in amic_range:

        x_val = 0
        y_val = 0
        first_iter_list = range(1, num)
        for val in first_iter_list:
            if (num%val)==0:
                x_val+=val

        for val in range(1, x_val):
            if (x_val%val)==0:
                y_val+=val

        if y_val==num:
            amicable_numbers.append(y_val)

    result = sum(amicable_numbers)

    return result

amicable_num_result = amicable_number(10000)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to be self-contained? We don't like looking problems up. Also, if you comment your code and tell us _why_ you did things this way, that would make it easier to help. Otherwise, your question might get closed for being unclear or too broad.

Comment: range(1,x) goes from 1 till x-1

Comment: You made the same mistake as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31795973/euler-21-extra-numbers-in-my-solution : you need a test `if x_val != y_val`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Euler problem 21, why are there extra numbers in my solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31795973/euler-problem-21-why-are-there-extra-numbers-in-my-solution)

Answer (score 1):

**Amicable numbers** are **two different numbers** so related that the sum of the **proper divisors** of each is equal to the other number. So, these numbers come in pairs.

A related concept is that of a **perfect number** which is a number that equals the sum of its own proper divisors. Your code does not differentiate between the two.

This implies that you have to add the condition `x_val != y_val` to your code.

Following is the fixed code along with a few cosmetic changes.

```python
def sum_amicable_numbers(x):
    # Use set instead
    amicable_numbers = set()

    # No point assigning the range to a variable
    for num in range(1, x):
        x_val = 0
        y_val = 0

        # No point assigning the range to a variable
        for val in range(1, num):
            if (num % val) == 0:
                x_val += val

        for val in range(1, x_val):
            if (x_val % val) == 0:
                y_val += val

        # Also check if x_val NOT equal to y_val
        if y_val == num and x_val != y_val:
            amicable_numbers.add(y_val)

    return sum(amicable_numbers)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sum_amicable_numbers(10000))
```